# Multiple calendars in FullCalendar

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

I checked the documentation and the example websites of FullCalendar but I didn't find anything about working with multiple calendars. How do they appear, mostly in the Agenda visualization like this one?

[Agenda visualization on FullCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCDej.png)

Thank you for any information

Marco

Comment: This is not "multiple calendars", this is simply using [Resources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-data) to create separate lists within each day. The view you're seeing in that visualisation is [this one](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view)

Comment: Using Resource is stil the only option to manage multiple calendars in FullCalendar?